# Laravel white screen when using Redirect Class

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-4

I am currently getting a white screen of death when I am trying to redirect my users using the Laravel Redirect class after handling data. If I use the native php-function header("location ...") the application responds correctly and sends the user on its merry way, but using Laravel's Redirect class the site crashes with a white screen of death. I have tried both the Redirect::action and Redirect::to functions, but they are both resulting in the same irritating white screen of death. The laravel.log shows nothing...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the code for the data handler controller class:

```
<?php
class ManagerLayoutDataController extends BaseController 
{
public function route($action, $moduleID) {
    if(method_exists('ManagerLayoutDataController',$action)) {
        $this->$action($moduleID);
    }
    // Invalid action (method not found)
    else {
        die('Action routing error');
        //return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}

public function updateHeaderBg($moduleID) {
    $image = Input::file('img');
    $user = Auth::user();
    $siteID = $user->getSiteID();

    $layoutDataMessage = null;

    // Validate file upload (NOT FILE CHARACTERISTICS)
    if(Input::hasFile('img') && $image->isValid() && isset($siteID) && $siteID !== "") {
        $res = ManagerFileUpload::uploadImage($siteID, $image);
        if($res->success) {
            $fileName = $res->fileName;
            $dbViewModule = ViewModuleRepository::getModule($moduleID);
            if($dbViewModule->type === DBViewModule::MODULE_TYPE_HEADER) {
                $headerModule = new HeaderModule($dbViewModule);
                $headerModule->updateBgImage($fileName);
                $layoutDataMessage = new LayoutDataMessage(LayoutDataMessage::STATUS_SUCCESS,"");
            }
        }
        else {
            $layoutDataMessage = new LayoutDataMessage(LayoutDataMessage::STATUS_FAIL,$res->message);
        }

    }
    else {
        $layoutDataMessage = new LayoutDataMessage(LayoutDataMessage::STATUS_FAIL, "Bilden kunde inte laddas upp.");
    }

    if($layoutDataMessage != null) {
        return Redirect::action('ManagerLayoutController@main')->with('message',$layoutDataMessage);
        //return Redirect::to('manager/layout/');
        //header('location: */manager/layout');
    }
    else {
        return Redirect::action('ManagerLayoutController@main')->with('message',LayoutDataMessage(LayoutDataMessage::STATUS_FAIL, "Bilden kunde inte laddas upp."));
        //return Redirect::to('manager/layout/');
        //header('location: */manager/layout');
    }
}
}
```

---

The Main Controller

---

```
<?php
class ManagerLayoutController extends BaseController 
{
    public function main() {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $siteID = $user->getSiteID();

        $moduleComposition = ViewModuleCompositionRepository::getCurrentInWorkModuleComposition($siteID);

        $dbViewModules = ViewModuleRepository::getModulesFromComposition($moduleComposition->id);

        $viewModules = array();

        foreach($dbViewModules as $dbViewModule) {
            switch($dbViewModule->getType()) {
                case DBViewModule::MODULE_TYPE_HEADER:
                    $viewModules[] = new HeaderModule($dbViewModule);
                    break;
                case DBViewModule::MODULE_TYPE_TEXT_SECTION:
                    $viewModules[] = new TextSectionModule($dbViewModule);
                    break; 
                case DBViewModule::MODULE_TYPE_KEY_METRICS:
                    $viewModules[] = new KeyMetricsModule($dbViewModule);
                    break;
                case DBViewModule::MODULE_TYPE_SLIDESHOW:
                    $viewModules[] = new SlideShowModule($dbViewModule);
                    break;
                case DBViewModule::MODULE_TYPE_VACANCIES:
                    $viewModules[] = new VacanciesModule($dbViewModule);
                    break;
                case DBViewModule::MODULE_TYPE_EMAIL_SUBSCRIPTION:
                    $viewModules[] = new EmailSubscriptionsModule($dbViewModule);
                    break;
                case DBViewModule::MODULE_TYPE_CO_WORKERS:
                    $viewModules[] = new CoworkersModule($dbViewModule);
                    break;
                case DBViewModule::MODULE_TYPE_NEWS_SECTION:
                    $viewModules[] = new NewsModule($dbViewModule);
                    break;
                case DBViewModule::MODULE_TYPE_INSTAGRAM_FEED:
                    $viewModules[] = new KeyMetricsModule($dbViewModule);
                    break;
                case DBViewModule::MODULE_TYPE_SOCIAL_MEDIA:
                    $viewModules[] = new KeyMetricsModule($dbViewModule);
                    break;
            }
        }

        $data = array(
            'siteID' => $siteID,
            'viewModules' => $viewModules
        );

        return View::make('dashboard.pages.manager.layout_main',$data);
    }
}
```

---

filters.php

---

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application & Route Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Below you will find the "before" and "after" events for the application
| which may be used to do any work before or after a request into your
| application. Here you may also register your custom route filters.
|
*/

App::before(function($request)
{
    //
});


App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    //
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following filters are used to verify that the user of the current
| session is logged into this application. The "basic" filter easily
| integrates HTTP Basic authentication for quick, simple checking.
|
*/

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});


Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic();
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Guest Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The "guest" filter is the counterpart of the authentication filters as
| it simply checks that the current user is not logged in. A redirect
| response will be issued if they are, which you may freely change.
|
*/

Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CSRF Protection Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The CSRF filter is responsible for protecting your application against
| cross-site request forgery attacks. If this special token in a user
| session does not match the one given in this request, we'll bail.
|
*/

Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});


/** Admin pages */
Entrust::routeNeedsRole( 'admin*', 'Admin', Redirect::to('/login'));



/** Manage pages */
Entrust::routeNeedsRole( 'manager*', array('Super Manager','Manager'), Redirect::to('/login'), false );


/**
 * Check view module ownership before editing data
 */

Route::filter('viewmodule.ownership', function($route) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $siteID = $user->getSiteID();

    $moduleID = $route->getParameter('moduleID');

    // Check that the module with $moduleID belongs to $siteID
    if(ViewModuleRepository::moduleBelongToSite($moduleID, $siteID)) {

    }
    // Unauthorized access
    else {
        die('Filter error');
        //Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

---

### routes.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'FrontController@main');

Route::get('/manager', 'ManagerHomeController@home');
Route::get('/manager/statistics', 'ManagerStatisticsController@main');
Route::get('/manager/resume-manager', 'ManagerResumeController@main');
Route::get('/manager/resume-manager/pending', 'ManagerResumeController@resumesPending');
Route::get('/manager/resume-manager/approved', 'ManagerResumeController@resumesApproved');
Route::get('/manager/resume-manager/rejected', 'ManagerResumeController@resumesRejected');
Route::get('/manager/layout', 'ManagerLayoutController@main');
Route::get('/manager/layout-old', 'OLDManagerLayoutController@main');

Route::post('/manager/layout/data/{action}/{moduleID}/', array('before'=>'viewmodule.ownership', 'uses' => 'ManagerLayoutDataController@route'));

Route::get('/manager/setup', 'ManagerSetupController@setup');

Route::get('/admin', 'AdminHomeController@home');
Route::get('/login', 'UsersController@login');

Route::get('/test', 'TestController@testMail');

// Confide routes
Route::get('users/create', 'UsersController@create');
Route::post('users', 'UsersController@store');
Route::get('users/login', 'UsersController@login');
Route::post('users/login', 'UsersController@doLogin');
Route::get('users/confirm/{code}', 'UsersController@confirm');
Route::get('users/forgot_password', 'UsersController@forgotPassword');
Route::post('users/forgot_password', 'UsersController@doForgotPassword');
Route::get('users/reset_password/{token}', 'UsersController@resetPassword');
Route::post('users/reset_password', 'UsersController@doResetPassword');
Route::get('users/logout', 'UsersController@logout');
```

Comment: So visiting the route directly doesn't give you the error but redirecting to it does?

Comment: Exactly. I am sending the user back to the main display (where they can edit data) after handling their input. I can show you the code for the controller where the user is sent if you think that would be helpful? 

It works correctly if I use the php header-function instead of Redirect.

Comment: Does the receiving controller require any parameters that are not being transferred when the redirect takes place? (I know this is probably a really obvious thing but I'm just trying to eliminate possibilities). It couldn't do any harm to include the controller code.

Comment: I am not in any way offended, please state anything that you can think of. I will include the main controller.

Comment: I am also adding filter.php and routes.php which are related.

Comment: I think you forgot a `new` here `with('message',LayoutDataMessage(LayoutDataMessage::STA...`

Comment: Ah, that is a typo which has been fixed. But I still get the same results. I have tried to remove the entire with function entirely, also switching to the Redirect::to function without the with function. Still the same frustrating results...

Comment: @ErikT : Haii... did solved this issue?? i'm also stuck at this issue in my project.. if you solved can u please share the solution??

Comment: The issue has not been solved, but I had to move on with development so I had to resolve to a provisional function using Session::put and the php header() function. I promise I will get back to this thread if I do solve it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It should at least tell you what is the actual error. 
This is only for development mode, remove it when you go into production

Comment: Where do I have to put this line in order for it to override the laravel error handler? 

I tried to put it on top of the index.php file, but I still get a white screen.

Comment: I stuck this at the top of routes.php and it seemed to work for me, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Look if there is a "return" before the Redirect. For example:

```
// Unauthorized access
else {
    die('Filter error');
    //Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Here should be **return Redirect::to('/');**